# How to use joda time DateTime with Thymeleaf

Tags: datetime, converters, spring-boot, jodatime, thymeleaf

I've the following controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String usage(Model model) {
    CallDataRecordLine calldatarecordline = new CallDataRecordLine();
    model.addAttribute("calldatarecordline",calldatarecordline);
    return "usage";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/usage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute CallDataRecordLine calldatarecordline, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("calldatarecordline",calldatarecordline);
    return "result";
}
```

The entity is described as follow

```
public class CallDataRecordLine {

    int chargedQuantity;
    String fromNumber;
    String toNumber;
    DateTime dt;
    String usage;
    String chargeableQuantity;
    //getters/setters
}
```

And the view linked to the controller

```
<form id="calldatarecordForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form"
    action="#" th:action="@{/usage}" th:object="${calldatarecordline}"
    method="post">

    <input type="text" th:field="*{fromNumber}" class="form-control" /> <input
        type="text" th:field="*{toNumber}" class="form-control" /> <input
        type="datetime" th:field="*{dt}" class="form-control" /> <input
        type="text" th:field="*{chargedQuantity}" class="form-control" /> <input
        type="text" th:field="*{usage}" class="form-control" /> <input
        type="text" th:field="*{chargeableQuantity}" class="form-control" />


    <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

Obviously, th:field is not able to convert jodaTime DateTime (I've tried removing the dt attribute and the CallDataRecordLine is created correclty). I saw that it was possible to use converter/formatter but I'm using spring-boot and I don't really know how to do it since all the configuration is load automatically. I tried both input type="text"/"datetime", none is working 
Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here take a look at this jodatime dialect https://github.com/gcwilliams/jodatime-thymeleaf-dialect

also I would leave the type="text" according to w3schools type datetime isn't supported by any browser http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Thank you, I've already managed to print an existing JodaTime Date with this :
`th:text="${#joda.mediumDate(date)}"` . But I cannot find how to do the allocation in a form with the <input th:field...> any idea ?

Comment: Be careful about using jodatime-thymeleaf-dialect in commercial projects, license is GPL